# Distinct Select ListItem from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

I have a list of objects of type quote that I'm passing to a view and showing in a grid. There are a number of drop down lists above the grid for filtering. I want to populate the `dropdown` lists with a distinct list of valid options based on the data for the grid. The one I'm looking at is 'Created By'.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCreatedBy(IEnumerable<Quote> quotes)
{

    var x = quotes.GroupBy(q => new {
             ListValue = q.CreatedBy.samAccountName, 
             ListText = q.CreatedBy.DisplayName})
                .Select(group => new SelectListItem { 
                      Value = group.ListValue, 
                      Text = group.ListText });

        return x;
    }
```

The error I'm getting is:

> 'IGrouping<,
>   Quote>' does  not contain a definition for 'ListValue' and no
>   extension method 'ListValue'  accepting a first argument of type
>   'IGrouping<,
>   Quote>' could be found (are you missing a using  directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

The 'Quote' has a 'User' object as the 'Created By' I want a DropDownList populated with the distinct Users samAccountName and DisplayName without having to re-query to get this list.

I've tried `.Distinct()` and different versions of the code above with `.GroupBy()`.

I'm new to `MVC` and really new to lambda expressions. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify a column on which you want to groupby. Please refer [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq) for GroupBy syntax.

Comment: Thanks Siva. I saw that example and I think it's different to what I'm trying to do.  I tried 'var x = quotes.GroupBy(q => q.CreatedBy.samAccountName, q => q.CreatedBy.DisplayName, (key, g)
                => new SelectListItem { Value = key, Text = g.First().ToString() });'. This gave me a list of all users, but there were duplicates in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GroupBy to get the distinct values and then use the first instance in the group to get your values.

```
var x = quotes
    .GroupBy(q =>
        new 
        {
            q.CreatedBy.samAccountName,
            q.CreatedBy.DisplayName,
        })
    .Select(q => 
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = q.First().CreatedBy.samAccountName,
            Text = q.First().CreatedBy.DisplayName,
        });
```